# VS generated help pages for WebAPI, property documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using Visual Studio 2013 auto-generated XML documentation for a Web API app and it is working well, except for with properties for business objects which inherit from List<>; all I get from them is "Collection of Object."

As an example, here is an Order object that contains an OrderLineCollection property:

```
public class Order 
{
    public OrderLineCollection Lines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineCollection : List<OrderLine>
{
    public void ReadFromServer(string orderNo)
    {}
}
```

The documentation generated for the Order object only has "Collection of Object" in the Type column for the Lines property, with no link to the OrderLine object.

If I instead define the Lines property like this, it works (=I get "Collection of OrderLine" in the Type column, with OrderLine hyperlinked):

```
public class Order 
{
    public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

However, I would like to be able to use an OrderLineCollection class as above so that I can keep my collection specific logic there. I just need for the XML documentation to say "Collection of OrderLine (hyperlinked)" for the Lines property.

Is there an easy way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

In your Web API project, open the code file for the class that is responsible for generating the help page model type names:

> {MyProject}/Areas/HelpPage/ModelDescriptions/**ModelDescriptionGenerator.cs**

go to the method:

```
public ModelDescription GetOrCreateModelDescription(Type modelType)
```

then go the following code inside the method:

```
if (modelType.IsEnum)
{
    return GenerateEnumTypeModelDescription(modelType);
}
```

and then type the following code **right after it**:

```
// Force Web API to generate help page model type names like "Collection of {MyType}" instead of "Collection of Object".
if (!modelType.IsGenericType                                // Model type must not be a generic type.
    && modelType.BaseType != null                           // Model type must have a base type (i.e. the model type is a derived type).
    && modelType.BaseType.IsGenericType                     // Model type base type must be a generic type.
    && typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(modelType.BaseType))  // Model type base type must implement the IList interface (you can replace "IList" with "IEnumerable" to handle more general collection types).
{
    // Set the model type variable to the model type base type and the rest of the method will know what to do.
    modelType = modelType.BaseType;

}
```

I hope this helps!